# Retrieve [binary data] from postgresql to pictureBox

Tags: c#, picturebox, npgsql, binary-data

I need some help retrieving  image [binary data] stored in a posgresql database column and displaying it in the pictureBox in C#. I inserted it using MemoryStream.

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you set the memorystream position to zero after writing and before reading.  The reading may fail if your graphic card doesn't support the graphic mode of the image.  I would try saving picture to a file.  The open file with your image view on machine to check if image is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
byte[] imgdata = (byte[])dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgdata);
pictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Thanks jdweng for dropping a comment.